# Constraint on sum from rows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I've got a table in PostgreSQL 9.4:

```
user_votes (
  user_id int,
  portfolio_id int,
  car_id int
  vote int
)
```

Is it possible to put a constraint on the table so a user max can have 99 point to vote with in each portfolio?
This means that a user can have multiple rows consisting of the same user_id and portfolio_id, but different car_id and vote. The sum on votes should never exceed 99, but it can be placed among different cars.

So doing:

```
INSERT INTO user_vores (user_id, portfolio_id, car_id, vote) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 20),
    (1, 1, 7, 40),
    (1, 1, 9, 25)
```

would all be allowed, but when trying to add something that exceeds 99 votes should fail, like another row:

```
    INSERT INTO user_vores (user_id, portfolio_id, car_id, vote) VALUES
    (1, 1, 21, 40)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately no, if you tried to create such a [constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-constraints.html) you will see this error message:

```
ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in check constraints
```

But the wonderfull thing about postgresql is that there is always more than one way to skin a cat. You can use a BEFORE [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) to check that the data you are trying to insert fullfills our requirements.

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger
>   manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e.,
>   subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does
>   not occur for this row). If a nonnull value is returned then the
>   operation proceeds with that row value.

Inside your trigger you would count the number of votes

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) into vote_count FROM user_votes WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
```

Now if vote_count is 99 you return NULL and the data will not be inserted.